# Error occured while flashing Galaxy Y with JELLYBLAST V3.0.2

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, samsung-galaxy-y

While installing ROM on my galaxy Y as per mentioned on [[ CUSTOM ROM - KERNEL] JELLYBLAST V3.0.2 for Galaxy Y GT-S5360](http://techcure.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/custom-rom-kernel-jellyblast-v3-0-2-for-galaxy-y-gt-s5360/)

ROM installation aborted with error:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Can’t open /sdcard/JELLYBLASTV3.signed.zip
(bad)
Installation aborted.
```

[image]

**Recovery.log**

```
-- Installing: /sdcard/JELLYBLASTV3.signed.zip
Finding update package...
I:Update location: /sdcard/JELLYBLASTV3.signed.zip
Opening update package...
minzip: Missed a central dir sig (at 0)
E:Can't open /sdcard/JELLYBLASTV3.signed.zip
(bad)
Installation aborted.
```

Comment: You should ask that in the Blog's page. The zip was updated so that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes normally for two reason.

1. You have a corrupted .zip so you should try re-downloading.
2. You have an unsupported recovery.

According to your ROM's requirements, You must have stock kernal. Most of the time while rooting, we flash a different kernal. So you may have to flash your stock kernal back again.
And also you must have a CWM recovery, as they say.  You can find it here http://techcure.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/how-to-root-and-use-cwm-for-galaxy-y-gt-s5360/

If you have already done these steps, please let me know. I will try to help as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you so much Murshid for your effort, I have CWM recovery and I tried via it. I downloaded CWM from the same site, so I hope it should work. As you said, my kernal has been modified while I rooted my phone. How can I get my stock kernal back ?

Comment: Here are some of the stock kernals for Samsung Galaxy Y https://hotfile.com/list/2023820/c55629e . I hope you can find yours here. You are welcome :)

Comment: Download the zip. Copy it to mobile. Boot your mobile into recovery mode. Wipe Cache Partition. Wipe Dalvic Cache. Flash the Zip. Reboot. Wait for 10 minutes. Then restart the phone into recovery again. Then try flashing the ROM

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to ask in the appropriate section on the XDA developers forum. The one for your rom can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1679563)
The creator of the rom should be able to help you. There are number of reason why you can't install the rom, the most probable for me is that your zip file didn't download properly. Double check the expected and downloaded file size for any discrepancies. Also make sure that your recovery mode supports installing custom ROMs

Comment: Actually, I have already asked this question on the forum from where I got the ROM and it was not only me searching for the solution of this problem. As I didn't get the solution, I asked here. Download is fine. I did it twice.

Comment: Then check if your recovery (ClockworkMod) supports installing ROMs from zip files. If you have required version of ClockworkMod recovery then as suggested below - you may need to install new kernel first.